# Casting non-integral types to structures

Tags: c, pointers, casting, structure

Please consider following code snippet:

```
typedef struct 
{
float x;
} str_t;

unsigned char data[4] = {0xFF,0xFF,0xFF,0xFF};
str_t st = *(str_t*)data;
```

The value in `str_t.x` is equal to `NaN`.
Could any one of you elaborate, why such casting is considered as undefined?

Assumptions:
Length of float is equal to 4 bytes

EDIT:
As pointed, NaN is not a "C" defined things, results were obtained under GCC + GDB. exact result for `str_t.x` was equal (according to Eclipse GDP plug-in) `-nan(0x7fffff)`

Comment: If you really want to muck with byte representations of `float`, read up on IEEE 754 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: It's considered undefined because an `unsigned char[4]` is not the same as an `str_t`. Pretty simple explanation...

Comment: Since a C implementation does not even need to support `NaN`, how would this code be defined behavior?  At _best_, it could be implementation defined behavior.  C does not define the bit pattern for `NaN` so "value in str_t.x is equal to NaN" may be your experience but not C defined behavior.